# Oracle 12c with Websphere 8.5 migration issue

Tags: java, oracle, websphere

In My application we were using WAS 6.x and Oracle 10g, we were using EJBs as Persistence layer. In EJBs we used predefined methods to store the data in the table as shown below

```
UsersLocalHome usrLocalHome =  (UsersLocalHome)getEJBLocalHome(Parameters.USERS_LOCAL_JNDI_LOOKUP);
      UsersLocal    usrLocal        =  usrLocalHome.create(getKey(Constants.USERS_MODULE), userTO, request.getUserInfo());
```

After the up-gradation from Websphere 6.x to Websphere 8.5 and Oracle 10g to Oracle 12c, we are getting following exception in the above peace of code

```
EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "findByPrimaryKey". Exception data: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xdb/XMLType
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getString(NamedTypeAccessor.java:410)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getString(GeneratedStatement.java:327)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getString(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:973)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.cci.WSRdbResultSetImpl.getString(WSRdbResultSetImpl.java:2827)
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.dataaccess.RawBeanData.getString(RawBeanData.java:1424)
```

Can some one pls help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you configured your data source in WebSphere to use the Oracle11gDataStoreHelper. For more information on data source configuration, see http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-base-dist&topic=rdat_minreqoracle.